# Not to able to get all the new commits between to branches when using git log inside GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to find all the new commits between two branches. I am using below script

```py
repo = Repo.init()
to_branch_remote = 'remotes/origin/%s' % (to_branch) # Remote Branch

new_commits = repo.git.log(f'{to_branch_remote}..HEAD', '--pretty=oneline')

LOGGER.info('New Commits here %s' % (new_commits))
no_of_commits = len(new_commits.split('\n'))
```

This script runs fine locally as expected and fetches all the new commits between the current head and the to branch. But when I run the same script inside the GitHub Actions workflows it just gives me one commit ID i.e. the latest one.

I even tried the `git log` command directly in actions but that too seems to return only one commit.

Here's my workflow:

```
name: Test New commits
run-name: Test New commits
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  test-new-commits:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.7' 
          cache: 'pip'
      - name: Test the git logs
        run: |
          git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
          git branch -a
          git log remotes/origin/feature/no-jira/workflow/my-testing-branch..HEAD --pretty=oneline
```

Thanks in advance!

- Tried with GitHub action
- Expected `git log` command to return all the new commit IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally, you have the complete git history.

By default, [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) doesn't fetch everything:

```
# Number of commits to fetch. 0 indicates all history for all branches and tags.
# Default: 1
fetch-depth: ''
```

So, you need:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

If you are doing something that needs the complete git history or you want to pick and choose, check its [usage](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage) for more details.